# Underscore template not rendering variable with <%-

Tags: templates, escaping, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have a simple template:

```
<div class='welcome'>Welcome <%- first_name %>!</div>
```

However my variable `first_name` is not rendered. This works fine:

```
<div class='welcome'>Welcome <%= first_name %>!</div>
```

and this correctly logs the variable:

```
<div class='welcome'>Welcome <%- first_name %><% console.log(first_name);console.log(typeof(first_name)); %>!</div>
```

which is of type `string` as expected. I couldn't find anyone with the same problem in the community. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

For context, this is used in a Marionette app that takes care of displaying the template.

Comment: hum maybe requirejs-tpl which I use to load the template. I could not reproduce it in a jsfiddle... Here is my `_.templateSettings`  `{evaluate: /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g, interpolate: /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g, escape: /<%-([\s\S]+?)%>/g}` It seems to be the same than in `underscore` source code.

Comment: It was indeed an issue relater to `requirejs-tpl`. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue related to `requirejs-tpl`. Here is a discussion of the [issue](https://github.com/ZeeAgency/requirejs-tpl/pull/11)

dawsontoth made a fix in his [fork](https://github.com/dawsontoth/requirejs-tpl)

To add it to your bower dependencies, add `"requirejs-tpl-dawsontoth": "*",` (it also depends on `requirejs-text`)